In flutter, NavigationRail.destinations[0].label.toString() returns 'Text{"Text")' instead of "Text"
I use NavigationRail & NavigationBar in my project. When I try to read the label of one of the destinations attached to NavigationRail, I get Text("Text") instead of "Text".
Here is an example code:
onDestinationSelected: (value) {
  context.goNamed(destinations[value].label.toString()); // output is "Text("Text")"
},

Is this an issue?
I tried same logic on NavigationBar and it works fine.
destinations[value].label.toString(); // Output is "Text"


You need to cast the label as a Text widget before accessing its data.
Here's how you can do it:
onDestinationSelected: (value) {
  context.goNamed((destinations[value].label as Text).data!);
}

The label property is a Text widget, not a String, so casting it first allows you to access the text content.

This worked. Thanks!

To resolve this, you need to access the actual text content within the label property. Here's how you can do it:
onDestinationSelected: (value) {
  context.goNamed(destinations[value].label.data.first.toString()); 
// Access the first text node
},       

